# Отображение данных из data через input в параграфе

Tags: vue.js

При вводе данных из data (в данном случае это будет - А) в поле input в параграфе должно выводиться значение "А", т.е. - א. Как это сделать? Там дальше весь алфавит будет.

```js
new Vue({
  el: ".app",
  data: {
    A: "א",
    message: ""
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <div class="app">
    <p>{{ A }}</p>
    <input type="text" v-model="message" />
    <p id="text">Текст : {{ message }}</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: ну так выводите `A`, а не `message`

Comment: Всего будет 22 буквы алфавита (иврит). Мне нужно выводить не 1 букву, а любую букву и любые сочетания букв, которые захочу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: ".app",
  data: {
    alphabet: {
       A: "א"
    },
    message: ""
  },
  computed: {
    translated() {
      return this.message.split('').map(item => {
          return this.alphabet[item] || '';
      }).join('');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <div class="app">
    <p>{{ translated }}</p>
    <input type="text" v-model="message" />
    <p id="text">Текст : {{ message }}</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: ".app",
  data: {
    Alphabet: "abcd",
    message: ""
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <div class="app" v-for="(letter, index)in Alphabet" :key="index>
    <p>{{ letter }}</p>
    <input type="text" v-model="letter" :value="letter" />
    <p id="text">Текст : {{ message }}</p>
  </div>
```

Писал "на коленке", без тестирования